# which function should I use to estimate a specific ARIMA model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a mydata.ts which is around 200 rows. I used stationary tests, took differences and examined `ACF` and `PACF`. So I decided to try `ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,1)` for instance.
Which R function should I use to find fitted values and forecasts? `Arima`, `arima` or `auto.arima`?
And can I trust the MAPE, MAD and other error results on `summary(model)`? Because I read an answer and it was saying the results are not the real but approximated or something.

Answer (score 0):

auto.arima will find the whole model specification that is the 'best' based on AIC, BIC.

IF you know the order (1,1,1) or (0,1,1) then use Arima from forecast package(same as arima, but little more general)

```
Arima(your_data, order=c(1,1,1)) will give the basic answer.
```

Seee the documentation for [forecast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf).

then actual out-of-sample forecast can be done with the forecast function.

Comment: it is not (1,1,1) or (0,1,1). it is seasonal, so it is ARIMA(1,1,1,)(0,1,1).